# Apologizing On Shabbath Day

Tags: repentance-teshuvah

Being that one is supposed to be happy on Shabbath, on The Shabbath Day, is one allowed to apologize to one they wronged?

Comment: Why is there a contradiction? Should one not be happy to right a wrong and be friends again?

Comment: @mbloch it's a good question because we are not allowed to do teshuva on Shabbat

Comment: @RabbiKaii can you source that?

Comment: @DoubleAA You really do keep this site emesdik, we owe you a huge debt. I was just saying what I was taught in yeshiva but I am finding it hard to look up. I'll keep looking and if I can't find anything I'll delete my comment (and probably open a question on Mi Yodeya!)

Comment: @RabbiKaii [Hidabroot](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/280889) quotes sources allowing teshuva on Shabbos - without tears.

Comment: @RabbiKaii There are some sources that suggest vidui should generally be avoided on Shabbos (as it is a type of supplication that can arouse distress in the person reciting it), though of course that's not the be all and end all of teshuva. Mishna B'rura (288:21), for  instance, indicates a person can express "*charatas 'avonos*" on Shabbos but should avoid a formal vidui (except in the context of a *ta'anis chalom* on Shabbos, in which case even vidui is permitted [*Sha'ar HaTziyun* ad loc.], as the whole idea of a *ta'anis chalom* is to relieve the distress a person is already experiencing).

Comment: @RabbiKaii [This source](http://www.hakhel.info/Sept09DailyEmail.html) cites R' Chaim Kanievsky that vidui is in the category of personal supplications that a person should not recite on Shabbos. See also [this article](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/35501) from Rabbi Kaganoff.